# Badly received question about Hamas corruption

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, deleted-questions

About a month ago, I asked two parallel questions:

- [Checks against corruption in the Palestinian Authority and their effectiveness](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/64174/checks-against-corruption-in-the-palestinian-authority-and-their-effectiveness)
- [Checks against corruption in Gaza, and their effectiveness](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/64175/checks-against-corruption-in-gaza-and-their-effectiveness)

The first question received modest upvotes and a [comprehensive and excellent answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/64290/36560). The second question received no answers, was downvoted, and auto-deleted.

(NB. I don't have enough rep to see the breakdown of up/downvotes.)

**Why was one question (apparently) well-received, while the other was not?**

Comment: Currently +6/-2 for the first one and +4/-3 for the second.

Comment: @Bobson is that difference significant?

Comment: Not really.  I just figured I'd provide the numbers since you can't see it on your own.

Answer (score 5):

As I see it, the two questions are the same, except that they ask about different groups / places: the Palestinian Authority (which is mostly/only in power in parts of the West Bank?) and Hamas (which is mostly/only in power in Gaza?).

I think there's nothing wrong with the questions per se. The remaining question attracted a few close votes but was left open after review. The auto-deleted question was not closed and there were no attempts to close it. It was [autodeleted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) after a month because there were no answers and it was negatively scored.

Seeing that the remaining question has yielded good answers, I don't see why the autodeleted question shouldn't be given a second chance. As such, I'll undelete the question.

Comment: I appreciate the undelete, but could you theorize as to why there's a difference? If I would have asked the same exact question about China and Venezuela, would there have been the same disparate response?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I'm not sure. One reason could be that the other question received a good answer, so it got more views and people were more inclined to upvote.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Probably people saw two very similar questions posted on the same day and got annoyed.